# Clarification regarding this line in the Oracle BI Publisher report designer guide?

Tags: bi-publisher

I'm reading this line in the Oracle [BI Publisher guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12844_01/doc/bip.1013/e12187/T421739T434255.htm)

> It is strongly recommended that you use a WHERE clause instead of a
>   group filter to exclude records from your extract.

This is a bit confusing to me.. what is the significance of using WHERE  over group filter?